# C++ OOP divide fractions

Tags: c++

it is my first post here sorry if it is irrelevant I will delete it.

I started learning C++, and I am currently learning OOP with OpenClassrooms.

It asked us at some point to overload some operators on our own to go further...

Here's the thing, I could do it, but I'm not sure to fully understand what happens(And I would like to be able to comment it in order to understand)

here's my code;

ZFraction.h

```
class Zfraction
{
public:
//Constructor
ZFraction(int num = 0, int denom = 1);

ZFraction& operator/=(ZFraction const& a);
//Other methods and operators
};

ZFraction operator/(ZFraction const& a, ZFraction const& b);
//Other prototypes
```

ZFraction.cpp

```
ZFraction& ZFraction::operator/=(const ZFraction& a)
{
    m_denom *= a.m_num;
    m_num *= a.m_denom;

    simplify(); //simplifies the fraction
    return *this;
}

ZFraction operator/(ZFraction const& a, ZFraction const& b)
{
    ZFraction copy(a);
    copy /= b;
    return copy;
}
```

and main.cpp

```
ZFraction a(8, 12);     
ZFraction b(7, 4);          
ZFraction c,d,e,f;
////////
f = a/b;

Output : 2/3 / 7/4 = 8/21
```

I had searched on the internet a lot in order to find a solution, didn't find anything and then end up finding it myself.

So my question is... How does that work exactly ? I'm really unsure...
Thank's for answering, let me know if this post is not relevant.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and let us know what part specifically do you not understand

Comment: Do you not understand the maths? The code? Operator overloading?

Comment: yes sorry, what I do not understand is how that works. What is my program doing for it to lead to that result ?

Comment: I think you have to post complete, working code and ask separate, specific questions about what specific parts of the code are doing. Even in a simple thing like this, there is a lot going on. C++ classes, constructors, reference parameters. operator overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator overloads are regular functions with funky names, and they are used through a simple transformation.

`a / b` is transformed into `operator/(a, b)`, since `operator/` is a free function.
`copy /= b` is transformed into `copy.operator/=(b)`, since `operator/=` is a member function.

That's all there is to it.
(As far as I know, this transformation idea came from CLU - the most influential programming language nobody's heard of.)

You can even use the functions directly in those forms.
It's not readable, but sometimes it helps when you need to figure out why things aren't evaluated in the way you expect.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing ?
Why is it if I change 
(ZFraction copy(a);
    copy /= b;)
to
(ZFraction copy(b);
    copy /= b;)
it doesn't work anymore ? But work for other operators such as +,- and * ?

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". (Dividing `b` by `b` of course doesn't produce the same result as dividing `a` by `b`.)

Comment: by doesn't work I mean the result is wrong, it outputs 1/1 (which is logical when I think about it) but I do not understand why it works perfectly fine for my * operator ?
Again sorry if that's just straight up stupid questions

Comment: > *Can I ask one more thing* Sure. Can you use the "Ask a Question" button on the upper right?

Comment: Do I just post a new question even if it is sort of linked to this one ?

Comment: @zabounet I don't see what the link is. Dividing a number by itself gives 1, of course. If your `*` operator multiplies one of the operands by itself and still manages to produce the correct result, there must be magic at work, but it has very little to do with this question.

Comment: Nevermind ! after using my brain a little bit I understood, thank's @molbdnilo for your answer. much appreciated (am I supposed to close the topic or something..?)

Comment: @zabounet If you're happy with the answer you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Alright thank you again, have a nice day !